# Angular 2 change position of element

Tags: angular

In a component template I have an image.
Dependent on a boolean I want to place another image on top of it.
The end result looks something like this: [image]

The second image is the green selector image.
In order to do so, I need to place the selector image dependent on the dimensions of the main title image.
ETA: Some images are higher than wide whereas others are wider then high. The top offset of the selector image is therefor dependent on the actual height of the title image.

I have an event handler for the `load` event of the images and when both are loaded I want to do the positioning.
Both images are available in the component via `@ViewChild`.
I tried to set the `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` properties of the `nativeElement` but they are read-only. I have verified that I have both images in my `load` handler with the correct dimensions.

How can I do that in either the template itself or in my `load` handler?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Angular. Pure CSS would be enough.

Comment: How? I don't know the dimensions of the title image. Fixed offsets for the selector image won't work.

Comment: Post HTML, without it it doesn't make sense to try to guess.

Comment: HTML won't tell you much. All you'll see are two img tags. See ETA in OP.

Comment: HTML would allow me to give you *exact* solution. But you are right, this is not important: I think you can position one image relative to common container.

Answer (score 26):

In case somebody else needs a solution for a similar problem:

I compute `top` and `left` position (based on the title image) in the `load` handler and in the template on the select image I added something like `[style.top]="top" [style.left]="left"` (where `top` and `left` are strings ending with "px").

Comment: Fo the sake of completeness. Use `[style.top.px]="top" [style.left.px]="left"` if using numbers as opposed to strings ending in "px".

Comment: For complete solution you need set position: relative attr for examole in css.